# SQL Server Profiler duration vs sp_whoisactive

Tags: sql-server

I know that the duration shown by SQL Server Profiler does not match with the duration (dd hh:mm:ss.mss) values for a given select statement. Does anyone know why it does not match. please correct me if I am wrong but my understanding is both are capturing are running queries at that moment. However trying to understand why `sp_whoisactive` will not match with Profiler.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some samples of how you came to your conclusion would be useful.  You also should read [this](http://whoisactive.com/docs/08_requests/) to understand how sp_whoisactive treats sleeping and active requests in regards to the time.

The definitions of what each Trace event means is defined on this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/sql-server-event-class-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) page

Comment: we were running a load test using  Apache Jmeter with inserts happening. I monitored using sp_whoisactive for those inserts and the duration was around 20ms but profiler was showing around 0 or 2 ms in the graphical user interface. I was not running server side trace as this is a test server. Trying to understand why the discrepency. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: I was able to look at sp_whoisactive and profiler durations and now able to understand. Thanks for those links. They make it clear.  Metrics reported by sp_whoisactive are more meaningful and accurate. Not saying profiler is showing wrong data but profiler does not cover the intrinsic details of sleeping and active requests to the depths of sp_whoisactive. Thanks much Martin. Appreciate your help.